# Iterate JSON object with changing key name

Tags: javascript, json

Is it possible to iterate over a JSON object where the keys contains an incrementing number?

The JSON in question is below:

```
{
  key0: 'adbid1,23',
  key1: 'adbid2,21',
  key2: 'adbid3,191',
}
```

Here is my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < objectLength; i++) {
  var submitray = query.key[i].split(","); //error
  var qid = submitray[0];
  var userAnswer = submitray[1];
}
```

Comment: what is the error message you get?

Comment: Well, that seems not a valid JSON. Is it just a JavaScript object?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object

Comment: Please clarify what your actual question is

Comment: My "keys" have a number..:.. I would like to reference them when iterating with a for loop

Comment: It's not stringifief sorry

Answer (score -2):

Try this instead:

```
var query = {
  key0: 'adbid1,23',
  key1: 'adbid2,21',
  key2: 'adbid3,191',
}

function a() {
  for(var i in query){
    var submitray = query[i].split(",");
    var qid = submitray[0];
    var userAnswer = submitray[1];
    console.log(userAnswer);
  }
}
a(); // init the function
```

https://repl.it/Ex3Y